# Firebase Storage upload task continuation never fires

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

## I am working on a project and I need to upload images to Firebase storage and get the download url before I can upload the associated model class to Firestore.

I am trying to use countdown latches to block the main thread until the upload is complete. I know there are better methods out there and feel free to recommend some but I figured I could just through up a brief load screen. The issue is that the callback for the getDownloadurl task never gets called. I have searched and searched and can't figure it out. Right now my code is straight from the documentation.

```
fun uploadListing(listing: Listing, images: ArrayList<ByteArray>, onCompleteListener: () -> Unit = {}) {
            val listingRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(LISTINGS_COLLECTION).document()
            val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
            listing.id = listingRef.id
            val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(images.size)

            var i = 0
            images.forEach {
                val imageRef = storageRef.child("images/${listing.id}/$i")
                val uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(it)
                uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        task.exception?.let { exception ->
                            throw exception
                        }
                    }
                    return@Continuation imageRef.downloadUrl
                }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        listing.images.add(task.result.toString())
                        countDownLatch.countDown()
                    } else {
                        // Handle failures
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
            countDownLatch.await()
            listingRef.set(listing).addOnSuccessListener {
                onCompleteListener()
            }
        }
```

My gradle dependencies...

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever block the main thread.  This is usually a terrible idea (as you have just discovered) and could cause your app to crash with an ANR.

If you want to register another callback when a bunch of tasks are complete, use one of the variants of [Tasks.whenAll()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) and pass it all the tasks you want to complete before moving to the next item of work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks like a great solution that would fix my issue so I'll mark as the answer. However, I ended up fixing it by using a method to upload one image at a time and in their call backs, recursively call the function for the next image. When the last image was uploaded, I called an on complete listener which was passed along through recursion to be executed in the callback.